# PWA maksable icon zoomed-in beyond the "safe zone"

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps

I have a [maskable icon](https://web.dev/articles/maskable-icon) that I've linked inside of my `manifest.webmanfiest` file like so:

```json
{
    "name": "آمادمی",
    "short_name": "آمادمی",
    "description": "آکادمی آنلاین فارسی",
    "lang": "fa-IR",
    "dir": "rtl",
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "white",
    "background_color": "white",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/icon-maskable.svg",
            "sizes": "any",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the [maskable.app](https://maskable.app) tool, I've made sure that the icon looks good within the so-called minimal "safe-zone":

[image]

And also using Chrome DevTools:

[image]

But on some Android devices (e.g. Xiaomi Redmi Note 8), when I add the shortcut to the home page, I get this:

[image]

I have been beating my head against the wall for quite some time now, I have absolutely no clue why this happens. Isn't a maskable icon supposed to be ***guaranteed*** not to be zoomed in beyond the so-called safe zone? Yet this is very much happening in my case.

Any ideas why?